# How to prevent weird behavior of radio buttons in Matlab GUI?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, radio-button

I have a gui with two radio buttons on it (both on the same uibutton group), 
and during a call to some internal gui function I find that it's possible to check BOTH radiobuttons.

Is it some known bug of the matlab gui, or it's possible to prevent this behavior by some property of the radio button?

I've tried to turn off the 'interruptble' and 'BusyAction' properties of the radio buttons, but it's still possible to check both when the gui is busy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen effects similar to what you're observing although under different circumstances. This is the expected behaviour, however, since the GUI by default should still take input even if the the application is busy in the background - it's then up to the application to decide whether or not to process this input.

You could explicitly prevent input from being accepted a few different ways:

- In your callback that responds to clicks on the radiobuttons, you could disable the radiobuttons before the long processing. If the radiobuttons are the only controls in your button group then you can do this easily in the buttongroup's `SelectionChangeFcn` by getting the handles to the radiobuttons, disabling them and using [DRAWNOW](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/drawnow.html) to refresh the GUI. You would then enable the radiobuttons after the processing completes.

  ```
  h = get(get(hObject, 'Parent'), 'Children');
  set(h, 'Enable', 'off');
  drawnow;
  %#
  %# LONG PROCESSING
  %#
  set(h, 'Enable', 'on');
  ```
- Use [BLURFIGURE](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30666-blurfigure-blurs-and-prevents-interaction-on-a-figure-window) in a similar way as above to disable the *entire* GUI during processing. With this method you could offer a **Cancel** button.

---